# Configuration precedence for resources in snakemake

Tags: snakemake

As far as I understand, resources available for rules can be configured in various ways in Snakemake.

1. In the snakefile, for a given rule:

```
rule my_rule:
    #[...]
    resources:
        mem_mb = 10240
```

2. In the `config.yaml` file contained in the directory provided to `option --profile` or `--worflow-profile` (either as default resources or per-rule resources):

```
default-resources:
    mem_mb: 4096
set-resources:
    my_rule:
        mem_mb: 10240
```

2. (bis) Scripts in the profile directory?
3. On the command-line (either as default resources or per-rule resources):

```
snakemake [...] --default-resources mem_mb=4096 --set-resources my_rule:mem_mb=10240
```

I suppose that rule-specific resources take precedence over default ones. But what happens if rule-specific or default resources are set simultaneously using several of the above ways? What are the precedence rules?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a rule to check pretty easily:

```
rule test:
    output: touch('output.txt')
    resources:
        my_resource='in rule'
    shell:
        "echo {resources.my_resource}"
```

And experiment away.  My guess is the order is (highest priority first).

1. set-resources in the command line
2. set-resources in a profile
3. the resource in the rule
4. default resources in the command line
5. default resources in the profile

Do report back if this is incorrect.

Note this behavior may not stay constant from version to version.  There are similar considerations in any config variable, which can be set in command line arguments, configfiles, etc.  I would recommend you strive for one source of "truth".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It seems that with snakemake 8.4.8 (and snakemake-executor-plugin-slurm version 0.3.1) the workflow specific settings for individual rules indeed take precedence over those defined in the snakefile. However, it seems that snakemake and its plugins are being heavilly worked on these days, so this might change.